# revert back refactoring step in Eclipse Java project

Tags: java, eclipse, refactoring, version

I was refactored class name in a large java source code in Eclipse. But in a situation where the refactoring produces any undesirable result, I would like to revered back to the previous class name or state of the code. Is there a way to revert back to the previous class name in Eclipse? Does it keep the versions of the refactoring stages?

Comment: `Ctrl + z` have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

Normally you can achieve this by just pressing undo. If this is not possible for any reason Eclipse will warn you.

In case of emergency: Revert by using your VCS :-)